# Trying to get the offset() values inside of a scroll event for "this" with jQuery, but getting "undefined" for this

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the `offset()` values inside of a scroll event for "this" with jQuery, but getting "undefined" for `this`.

Code for my particular use-case, with comments about what happens:

```
$canvas_frame.contents().find(".ar4 .Tm.aeJ").scroll(function(event){
        log("SCROLLING!");
        log(this); // successfully logs the DOM element in the console
        log($(this).offset()); // ERROR
        log($(this).css("top")); // works
    });
};
```

So, while all the elements are successfully detected, calling the .offset() method on the jQuery selector element fails: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageYOffset' of undefined`

How can I get that value without it failing?

#### Update

I have corrected the error message that I'm actually getting for this example.

#### Update 2

What I have noticed, is that it takes a moment for the element to be logged to the console, as if initially the jQuery result is empty, but afterwards it gets filled in. Any ideas?

#### Update 3

I have created a demo with JSFiddle, which works in a simple page. http://jsfiddle.net/victorbstan/PBfNu/ 
However, my code is trying to find elements inside of an iframe, the script is embedded in the page, through a Chrome Extension. I'm still wondering why my code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo, but it's not `offeset()` but `offset()`. Also `offset()` returns an object with left and top values.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, corrected in the example, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a full answer because I'm still not sure how to work around it. But it might help.

I think this is caused by http://crbug.com/20773. I originally tried using this patch:

```
$ sed -ri 's/(win\.page[XY]Offset)/win \&\& \1/' jquery.js
```

At that point the errors vanished, though I sometimes got `null` as the `offset()` result.